# How to make a Rss feed parser

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that parse an Rss feed and convert it into Json file that is showed in a recycler view.

How can I show directly the Rss feed without convert it in a Json?

I've created external classes that contain items and functions. These classes consist of constructors used to populate the array map.

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RSSObject rssObject;

//RSS link
private final String RSS_link="http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/Science.xml";
private final String RSS_to_Json_API = "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("News");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager  = new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    loadRSS();
}

private void loadRSS() {
    AsyncTask<String,String,String> loadRSSAsync = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

        ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            mDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String result;
            HTTPDataHandler http = new HTTPDataHandler();
            result = http.GetHTTPData(params[0]);
            return  result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
            rssObject = new Gson().fromJson(s,RSSObject.class);
            FeedAdapter adapter = new FeedAdapter(rssObject,getBaseContext());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    StringBuilder url_get_data = new StringBuilder(RSS_to_Json_API);
    url_get_data.append(RSS_link);
    loadRSSAsync.execute(url_get_data.toString());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_refresh)
        loadRSS();
    return true;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rss` is `xml` file , so if you want to retreive data from `Rss` feed without going through `json` so you need to read from that `xml` file , to do the job im using this method :

```
    public void parseXml(String xml){

    ArrayList<Articles> articles = new ArrayList();
    Articles currentArticle = new Articles();

    try {

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput( new StringReader(xml)); // pass input whatever xml you have

        boolean insideItem = false;

        for(int eventType = xpp.getEventType(); eventType != 1; eventType = xpp.next()) {
            if(eventType == 2) {
                if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    insideItem = true;
                } else {
                    String pubDate;
                    if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        if(insideItem) {
                            pubDate = xpp.nextText();
                            currentArticle.setTitle(pubDate);
                        }
                    } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                        if(insideItem) {
                            pubDate = xpp.nextText();
                            currentArticle.setLink(pubDate);
                        }
                    } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("dc:creator")) {
                        if(insideItem) {
                            pubDate = xpp.nextText();
                            currentArticle.setAuthor(pubDate);
                        }
                    } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("category")) {
                        if(insideItem) {
                            pubDate = xpp.nextText();
                            currentArticle.addCategory(pubDate);
                        }
                    } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("media:thumbnail")) {
                        if(insideItem) {
                            pubDate = xpp.getAttributeValue((String)null, "url");
                            currentArticle.setImage(pubDate);
                        }
                    } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                        if(insideItem) {
                            pubDate = xpp.nextText();
                            if(currentArticle.getImage() == null) {
                                currentArticle.setImage(getImageUrl(pubDate));
                            }

                            currentArticle.setDescription(pubDate);
                        }
                    } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("content:encoded")) {
                        if(insideItem) {
                            pubDate = xpp.nextText();
                            if(currentArticle.getImage() == null) {
                                currentArticle.setImage(getImageUrl(pubDate));
                            }

                            currentArticle.setContent(pubDate);
                        }
                    } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")) {
                        Date pubDate1 = new Date(xpp.nextText());
                        currentArticle.setPubDate(pubDate1);
                    }
                }
            } else if(eventType == 3 && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                insideItem = false;
                articles.add(currentArticle);
                currentArticle = new Articles();
            }
        }
      itemList.setAdapter(new ListArticleAdapter(articles, MainActivity.this));
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So instead of using a list of `RssObject` , im using a list of `Articles` , hope you understand my code !